# How to temporarily unbind event in tkinter.Text?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I have trouble with disabling `'<<Modified>>'` event in tkinter.Text widget. Why unbind() does not work in this example?

```
from tkinter import *


def on_modify(event):
    print('Modified - this should never happen')


root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
text = Text(root)
mod_id = text.bind('<<Modified>>', on_modify)

# test - how to temporarily disable Modified event?
text.unbind('<<Modified>>', mod_id)
# text.unbind_all('<<Modified>>')
text.insert(END, 'test')
mod_id = text.bind('<<Modified>>', on_modify)

text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try using `.after` to schedule the insertion for after the main loop has had a chance to update the binding?

Comment: or you can add a `text.update()` just after you insert the `"test"` inside the `tkinter.Text`